# get text from each element

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

need to get amount text and check if it < 5000 then click next element in class

```
<div class="single sort">
    <div class="svariant front one" id="114_0">
        <img src="http://pics.avs.io/al_square/24/24/TK@2x.png" class="airlogo"    title="Turkish Airlines">
        <div class="amount">4 479
            <span class="rub">Р</span>
        </div>
      <a href="/travel/Order/Index/h7676Rn7471rdd?fid=349&amp;come=0" class="yellow front">BUY</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="single sort">
    <div class="svariant front one" id="113_0">
        <img src="http://pics.avs.io/al_square/24/24/TK@2x.png" class="airlogo"    title="Turkish Airlines">
        <div class="amount">9 479
            <span class="rub">Р</span>
        </div>
        <a href="/travel/Order/Index/h7676Rn7471rdd?fid=349&amp;come=0" class="yellow front">BUY</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I get value < 5 000 i clicked 'index +1'. How do this in cycle?

```
browser.div(:class => 'single sort', :index => 0).div(:class, 'amount').text
```

Formatting the text this way

```
sum = browser.div(:class => 'single sort', :index => 0).div(:class, 'amount').text
sum.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '')
sum = sum.to_i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) and then iterate over it, which allows for incrementing the index.  Here's a hacky, contrived example:

```
(0..1).each do |i|
  amount =  b.div(:class => 'single sort', :index => i).div(:class, 'amount').text.gsub!(/\D/, "")
  amount = amount.to_i
  next if amount < 5000
  puts amount               #=> 9479
end
```

Since there are no `<a>` tags in the HTML snippet, it's not clear what should be clicked, but you could potentially replace `puts amount` with the `click` action.

Answer (score 1):

here is more universal way, for any range of given elements, without the hardcoded (0..1), be there 2 elements, or 324834 :)

```
b.divs(:class => 'single sort').each {|x| if x.text.gsub!(/\D/, "").to_i<5000; puts x.text; else; puts "The value is #{x.text}"; end}
```

Comment: i need to change index of clicked element each time, when amount lower than 5k. but thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the first one after the element that is less than 5000, I think it would be easier to find the first element that is 5000 or greater. Looking at the problem this way, you can simply create an element collection of the divs. Then `find` the first one where the text matches the specified condition.

```
match = browser.divs(class: 'single sort').find do |div|
    div.div(class: 'amount').text.tr('^0-9', '').to_i >= 5000
end
match.link(class: 'yellow front').click
```

If you prefer to find the first one after the one that is less than 5000, you could use the `drop_while` method instead. After dropping the ones that do not meet the criteria, the first element in the collection will be greater than the 5000.

```
matches = browser.divs(class: 'single sort').drop_while do |div|
    div.div(class: 'amount').text.tr('^0-9', '').to_i < 5000
end
matches.first.link(class: 'yellow front').click
```

Comment: i wasn't completely honest with you, element I getting amount `div(class: 'single sort')`, element I must click `a.(:class, 'yellow front')`.
that's why orde's way fits better

Comment: But where is that `<a>` element? It is not anywhere in your provided HTML.

Comment: it's ok! but if developers add another numbers in `tr` we will get not proper result. need to target amount div. thank you for help!

Comment: You do have the option of scoping the text check to the amount div (see update). Anyways, I was just trying to show the concept of using methods that do not require you manually calling `break`.